# how do i select each button such that i get its value when i press them

Tags: javascript, html, css

for example: i have a calculator app where all buttons have certain values. i want the value to be shown in the... text box
,,,

```
<button class="grey" value="ac">ac</button>
<button class="grey" value="">+/-</button>
<button class="grey" value="%">%</button>
<button class="coral" value="➗">➗</button>
<button class="dark" value="7">7</button>
<button class="dark" value="8">8</button>
<button class="dark" value="9">9</button>
<button class="coral" value="X">X</button>
<button class="dark" value="4">4</button>
<button class="dark" value="5">5</button>
<button class="dark" value="6">6</button>
<button class="coral" value="minus">-</button>
<button class="dark" value="1">1</button>
<button class="dark" value="2">2</button>
<button class="dark" value="3">3</button>
<button class="coral" value="add">+</button>
<button class="zero" value="0">0</button>
<button class="dark" value=".">.</button>
<button class="coral" value="equal">=</button>
```

,,,

Comment: the value of the button ? or the calculated value ? anyway your question is very unclear. Also please show what you have done trying to solve your problem. You could start by searching : ' selecting multiple elements with javascript '  and/or 'getting value of clicked element javasript'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can loop through all of the buttons and a click event listener to each.

```js
buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");

buttons.forEach(function(btn) {

  btn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.value)
  });

});
```

```html
<button class="grey" value="ac">ac</button>
<button class="grey" value="+">+</button>
<button class="grey" value="-">-</button>
<button class="grey" value="%">%</button>
<button class="coral" value="➗">➗</button>
<button class="dark" value="7">7</button>
<button class="dark" value="8">8</button>
<button class="dark" value="9">9</button>
<button class="coral" value="X">X</button>
<button class="dark" value="4">4</button>
<button class="dark" value="5">5</button>
<button class="dark" value="6">6</button>
<button class="coral" value="minus">-</button>
<button class="dark" value="1">1</button>
<button class="dark" value="2">2</button>
<button class="dark" value="3">3</button>
<button class="coral" value="add">+</button>
<button class="zero" value="0">0</button>
<button class="dark" value=".">.</button>
<button class="coral" value="equal">=</button>
```

Comment: thanks my man. i just found out i had to use queryselector all

Answer (score -1):

You can assign the button value first on your HTML file and using JavaScript to assign the text to your buttons according to their values. Below you can see the code.

```
<html>
<body>
<button class="grey" value="ac"></button>
<button class="grey" value="+/-"></button>
<button class="grey" value="%"></button>
<button class="coral" value="➗"></button>
<button class="dark" value="7"></button>
<button class="dark" value="8"></button>
<button class="dark" value="9"></button>
<button class="coral" value="X"></button>
<button class="dark" value="4"></button>
<button class="dark" value="5"></button>
<button class="dark" value="6"></button>
<button class="coral" value="-"></button>
<button class="dark" value="1"></button>
<button class="dark" value="2"></button>
<button class="dark" value="3"></button>
<button class="coral" value="+"></button>
<button class="zero" value="0"></button>
<button class="dark" value="."></button>
<button class="coral" value="="></button>
</body>
<script src="yourjavascriptfile.js"></script>
</html>

var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
   buttons[i].innerText = buttons[i].value;
}
```